# I want to set a session and link customer id with tour id inside a session

Tags: php, html

I want to link customer id with tour id and store them in a session but every time I click submit I get the message that my session doesn't exist, which means it's not being set.

I tried doing this.

```
session_start();

extract($_POST);

if(isset($_SESSION['requests'])) {
    $_SESSION['requests'] = array($cid, $tid);
}

<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action='InsertMakeTourReservation.php'>
            CustomerID:<input name='cid' /> <br />
            TourID:<input name='tid' /> <br />
            <input type='submit' value="Submit" />
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click submit my form should execute the action, but the if condition immediately gives me session does not exist.

Comment: You need to provide more details as there are a lot of variables that we don't know where they're defined. And I think you may be confusing $_POST with $_SESSION.

Comment: here's the other program that i want the above form to execute once the session is set: <?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['requests']))
 die("session doesn't exist");

 try{
  require('connection1.php');
  $counter=0;
  foreach($_SESSION['requests'] as $cid->$tid){
   $sql="insert into reservations values (NULL,$cid,$tid,now())";
    $counter+= $db->exec($sql);
  }
  echo "$counter rows have been inserted";
 $db=NULL;}
 
 catch(PDOException $e)
   {
     die($e->getMessage());
   }
 
?>

Comment: Where are you setting `$_SESSION['requests']`? Cos if it's not previously set, the IF condition will keep failing